# sed to replace partial string

Tags: regex, shell, unix, sed

I would like to do the following by using sed

**case 1:**

```
*here is some random text constant=randomValue some more random text*
```

I would like to replace randomvalue directly after constant= while keeping the rest of the line intact so the result would look like:

```
*here is some random text constant=substituteValue some more random text*
```

**case2:**

```
*here is some random text constant= randomValue some more random text*
```

similar to the first one but with a space after the constant= string, so the output would be

```
*here is some random text constant= substituteValue some more random text*
```

For case one i've been trying to use:

```
echo $line | sed 's/server=.*\ /sever=\<SrvrName\>/'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this sed:

```
sed 's/\( constant = *\)[^ ]*/\1substituteValue/' <<< "$line"
```