# Match and Replace ![foo](/bar/) with Regex in SED

Tags: regex, bash, sed, pattern-matching, posix

I'm trying to write a RegEx for SED to make it match and replace the following MarkDown text:

```
![something](/uploads/somethingelse)
```

with:

```
![something](uploads/somethingelse)
```

Now, in [PCRE](https://www.pcre.org/) the matching pattern would be:

```
([\!]|^)(\[.*\])(\(\/bar[\/])
```

as tested on Regex101:

[image]

but on SED it's invalid.

I've tried **a lot** of combinations before asking, but I'm going crazy since I'm not a RegEx expert.

**Which is the right SED regex to match and split that string** in order to [make the replacement with sed as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21146256/1654265)?

Comment: Show how you are using the `sed` command. If you use capturing `(` and `)` unescaped you need to use `-E` option. Also, bracket expressions do not support escape sequences in POSIX regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `find . -name '*.md' -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/source/target/g'`

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducible example?

Comment: OMG you could have solved it with -E o_O stay tuned I'm trying :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: `sed -E 's/([\!]\[.*\])(\(\/uploads[\/])/\1(uploads\//g' <<< "\![aaa](/uploads/aaa/aaa)"` it works! As simply as that! Please convert your comment into an answer so I can accept it, thank you a lot

Comment: Why not just try this sed 's/](\//](/' It replaces '](/' to ']('

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi I need to target only markdown images `![]()`, not links `[]()`, and only images loaded into GitLab's Wiki inner resource folder, which is /uploads, so `![](/uploads/)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sed` command you need should be run with the `-E` option as your regex is POSIX ERE compliant. That is, the capturing parentheses should be unescaped, and literal parentheses must be escaped (as in PCRE).

You may use

```
sed -E 's;(!\[.*])(\(/uploads/);\1(uploads/;g'
```

**Details**

- `(!\[.*])` - Capturing group 1:

  - `!` -  a `!` char (if you use `"..."`, you need to escape it)
  - `\[.*]` - a `[`, then any 0+ chars and then `]`
- `(\(/uploads/)` - Capturing group 2:

  - `\(` -  a `(` char
  - `/uploads/` - an `/uploads/` substring.

The POSIX BRE compliant pattern (the actual "quick fix" of your current pattern) will look like

```
sed 's;\(!\|^\)\(\[.*](\)/\(uploads/\);\1\2\3;g'
```

Note that the `\(...\)` define capturing groups, `(` matches a literal `(`, and `\|` defines an alternation operator.

**Details**

- `\(!\|^\)` - Capturing group 1: `!` or start of string
- `\(\[.*](\)` - Capturing group 2: a `[`, then 0+ chars, and then `(`
- `/` - a `/` char
- `\(uploads/\)` - Capturing group 3: `uploads/` substring

See the [online sed demo](https://ideone.com/6KHKZa)

The `;` regex delimiter helps eliminate escaping `\` chars before `/` and make the pattern more readable.

Comment: For the records, I've mentioned you here: https://gitlab.com/Andrea.Ligios/Wiki2PDF/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml#L72 . Still thank you for the great answer, cheers

Comment: @AndreaLigios Still, `sed -E -i 's/([\!]\[.*\])(\(\/uploads[\/])/\1(uploads\//g'` does not look pretty. I'd use `sed -E -i 's,(!\[.*])\(/uploads/,\1(uploads/,g'`